# Is there a KornShell (ksh) IDE for Windows?

Tags: shell, unix, ssh, editor, ksh

My job is to write KornShell (ksh) script and run the script in a remote server. I am trying to find the best way to do it.

Currently, I edit the code in Notepad++, transfer the file to server (through FTP), run the script in server, and repeat the process until the script runs fine.

So, what I'm looking for is an IDE (for windows) with a good editor, ftp support and debugging facilities.

Comment: netbeans and eclipse both have excellent support for ftp/debugging

Comment: I added some additional tags to get more eyes on your question, in case my answer is not sufficient. Feel free to change them as you see fit, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both Vim and Emacs will edit files on a remote machine somewhat transparently and both have ports to Windows that work well.

This [link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Edit_remote_files_locally_via_SCP/RCP/FTP) will tell you how to do it with Vim.

Answer (score 4):

what you need is just an editor with syntax highlighting feature.
Personally, I prefer the combination of winscp and notepad2. Configure your winscp to use notepad2 as editor. Then, locate the remote script file in winscp, right click and select Edit. You can now start coding and for every moment you press CTRL+S (save) in your notepad2, winscp will detect and transfer to the server.

Comment: This is exactly how I've been writing shell scripts for most of this year. Nice and simple, and I can take advantage of our exisitng windows-based source control system.

Answer (score 4):

The [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com) editor can do seamless FTP/SFTP editing.

As to debugging it might also be possible to run the remote script using something like [plink](http://www.zeusedit.com/zforum/viewtopic.php?t=1549).

Answer (score 2):

I recommend opening a terminal connection to the remote machine (ssh or X windows) and edit/test/debug the script there. Unless you can get an X connection going, you'll have to use a text-mode editor like vi or emacs (steep learning curves but very powerful), or something simple like pico/nano. You can copy the file back to your Windows machine when you are all done. This approach isn't too bad. I do it all the time.